# Reload a route method if 504(gateway timeout) happens

Tags: node.js, express

I am building a nodejs application with expressjs framework.Recently I faced some critical problem where one route method is facing 504 timeout as it takes too much time for getting the output of a certain query.I optimise  the query and database but no use.It still getting 504 timeout.My question is can I reload the route method if it gets 504 timeout?

Comment: Normally a 504 error can occur when *This server did not receive a timely response from an upstream server it accessed to deal with your HTTP request* where in which your query optimization could contribute to some extent, and you may have to check beyond that too.

Answer (score 0):

What you mean by reload? You can do same request to this route and it will be started again. And if it will have same time to process it will get timeout again. To solve this ptoblem you need:

- create separated process which will do long work (do db request)
- perform checking of long work process to not start again until it finished
- return responce to wait or result if result is ready

You can start process each time or you can create microservice daemon and communicate to it via some kind of rpc (for example json-rpc)